# Liquibase diff change sets and a database

Tags: liquibase

I am developing and have made changes to a db. Before I commit I have to add the change to my change sets. So I do `liquibase --url="...;name=db_dev" diff` but it asks me for reference parameters. However I do not want to compare the url db with another db. I want to compare the change sets (files) with a target db.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be using Liquibase in a non-standard way.

One expected usage pattern is that you create the necessary schema changes by authoring a Liquibase "change set" (in either XML, JSON, or Liquibase structured SQL) and then using `liquibase update` to deploy that change to each of your database instances.

A second usage pattern has you make changes directly to a database using whatever database manipulation tool you prefer, and then using `liquibase diffChangelog` to append the corresponding change set to your changelog file. After making the change set, you then have to use the `liquibase changelogsync` command to populate the Liquibase `DATABASECHANGELOG` table on the database with the information that the new changeset has already been 'deployed' to the database. The second usage requires that you either:

- compare two live databases (for example, you could compare a 'test' or 'staging' database to whichever database you manually changed)
- create a database 'snapshot' before making the manual change, then make the change, and then compare the database to the snapshot. [This page on the Liquibase blog](http://www.liquibase.org/2015/07/without-a-connection.html) describes how to use the `liquibase snapshot` command to take a snapshot, and how to use that snapshot as an 'offline database' to compare to.

[This page in the Liquibase documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html) has some more details on usage patterns when getting started with Liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
liquibase status --verbose
```

https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/change-tracking/status.html